# javascript parseFloat bug

Tags: javascript, php, parsefloat

I am subtracting multiple textboxes using JavaScript. I'm adding the total amount in the textboxes.When amount is first entered it works fine but when I change the amount and save it again there is a bug.The value is pulled from database the second time and is in "00.00" format.

The problem is when the value is a 4 digit value say "6500.00" it changes to "6.00". It shows as 6500.00 in the webpage but during calculation in JavaScript it calculates as "6.00".it works fine for 3 digit value like "400.50".Can somebody tell me what's the problem here.

JavaScript:

```
function fill_balance() 
{
var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
var payment = document.getElementById("payment").value; 
document.getElementById("balance").value = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(payment);
}
```

P.S: I use number_format() function to change the format to 00.00

Comment: Are you sure you're not including some separator between the thousands place and the remainder?  For instance, in the USA, we would probably have "6,500.00".  That comma would explain the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't something like `6 500.00`?

Comment: FACEPALM!there's a comma as seperator when data is pulled.Removing it now!Thanks for the responses!